# Why isn't the type attribute being applied to dataList?

Tags: list

I have a custom component with a dataList component within:

```
<apex:dataList value="{!itemsList}" var="item" type="{! listType }">
    <apex:outputText value="{!item}"/>
</apex:dataList>
```

This works well, except that the `type` attribute doesn't work. The output looks like this:

```
<ul id="j_id0:emailTemplate:j_id3:j_id4:j_id18:j_id19:j_id20" type="1">
    <li id="j_id0:emailTemplate:j_id3:j_id4:j_id18:j_id19:j_id20:0">Something</li>
    <li id="j_id0:emailTemplate:j_id3:j_id4:j_id18:j_id19:j_id20:1">Something else</li>
    <li id="j_id0:emailTemplate:j_id3:j_id4:j_id18:j_id19:j_id20:2">Something more</li>
    <li id="j_id0:emailTemplate:j_id3:j_id4:j_id18:j_id19:j_id20:3">Something too</li>
</ul>
```

Notice how the type is set, but the list is unordered. I assume that a value of `1` would indicated an ordered list. I've also tried `A` with no change.

From [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dataList.htm):

> The type of list that should display. For ordered lists, possible values include "1", "a", "A", "i", or "I". For unordered lists, possible values include "disc", "square", and "circle". If not specified, this value defaults to "disc".

I've also tried omitting the `type` attribute, which does not apply the value `disc` as the docs imply it should.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dataList.htm) seems to be incorrect as Visualforce engine seems to always generate [`apex:dataList`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dataList.htm) as an unorder list in HTML; hence it defaults to `disc`.

---

This could be due to the fact that the [`type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) attribute on ordered list was deprecated in HTML4, but reintroduced in HTML5. For type attribute, the [`documentation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) for `<ol>` in mozilla says:

> Unless the value of the list number matters (e.g. in legal or technical documents where items are to be referenced by their number/letter), the CSS list-style-type property should be used instead.

---

In case if its absolutely needed, you could style the list with [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type), some exampe values as `lower-roman`, `upper-roman`, etc. small example

```
<!-- pardon the inline style, ideally CSS should be via style classes -->
<apex:dataList value="{!itemsList}" var="item" type="{! listType }" 
    style="list-style-type: lower-roman;">
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually looking to toggle the list as ordered or unordered based on a component attribute and don't care much about style. I guess I'll be duplicating markup and using `rendered`.

Comment: Better approach would be to make the style class dynamic based on whether its order or unordered list. For instance, `style="{!IF(ListType == 'ordered', 'list-style-type: lower-roman;', '')}"`

Comment: I don't understand. There won't be a style class. I'm merely looking to let the component user indicate whether an `ol` or `ul` list type is desired.

Comment: Not really sure about your use case, but what I am saying is you could style the `apex:dataList` to look like an order or unorder list with CSS conditionally

Comment: Ah, as in `list-style-type: decimal` to [convert a UL to an OL](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9jq6d513/). Nice.

Comment: [Thomas](https://twitter.com/tet3) shared a [link](https://twitter.com/tet3/status/1139635303646474240) of [similar question](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000968lIAA) asked on developer forum in 2009. :)